# HTML elements are shown bigger on my site as compared to original one?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins

I am using different jQuery plugins on my site. For example **jQuery Notice**, **jQuery bloackUI** and **jQuery UI DatePicker**. But all these are shown bigger on my site when compared to original one with same configuration, on same browser and with same resolution. There are many css files in my site but I don't know what is effecting the size of all these. Any Idea ? Thanks

**Example 1:**

**Original on Plugin official site:**

[image]

**On My website:**

[image]

**Example 2**

**Original on Plugin official site:**

[image]

**On My site:**

[image]

Comment: Try installing Firebug and inspecting the elements to see what CSS is affecting it.

Comment: My guess is you need to adjust the location of the css files included with the jquery ui download. When the right css rules are applied, the datepicker will be sized like the smaller version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery UI sites got

```
body {
   font-size: 10px
}
```

Rest of sizes, also jQuery UI dialogs, datepickers etc, got sizes relatively to that.

Just check: http://jsfiddle.net/6YfGc/

Comment: Yes it is working now and all plugin elements are normal. It effected my other fonts on website but main problem is solved.. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use a DOM inspector (Chrome's Inspect Element tool, IE's Developer Tools, Firebug...) to see what styles are being applied to your elements. Find out what's overriding what and fix it like that.

Answer (score 2):

Install something like FireBug.  That will allow for you to see what CSS rules are affecting the different elements in the DOM.  Then you'll be able to trace it back to the specific line in the specified stylesheet.  After that point, you can either change the rogue rule, OR you can set up a more specialized rule of your own, to have it display the way you want.